# Tests not running with Junit 5 and Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit5

I am trying to run Jacoco test coverage for my project. When I use the command `mvn clean package` from the terminal, the test cases won't run. But when I run the same tests using IntelliJ, everything works fine.

My maven version is `3.6.3`. These are the versions of the dependencies and plugin in the `pom.xml`

```
<maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.22.1</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
<maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
<jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.5</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
<junit-jupiter.version>5.7.0</junit-jupiter.version>
```

I am using the Springboot starter parent

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
```

I spent an awful amount of time trying to figure out the issue, but no joy. Below are the few of the many links I tried. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63875520/maven-surefire-not-running-junit-5-tests)
[Link 2](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2169)
[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53433663/maven-not-running-junit-5-tests)

Comment: Show one of your test classes and also your full pom file ... ... Apart from that I doubt the Maven version cause `3.6.3_1` does not exist... only `3.6.3`... I would suggest to use a more recent version of surefire/failsafe plugin at least 2.22.2 or even better 3.0.0-M4...

Comment: Sorry about the maven version. It was a typo. I updated the right version in the question. 
I tried to run with 2.22.2 as well, didn't work. Let me try with the 3.0.0-M5.

Comment: Please show a test class. Your imports may be wrong.

Comment: I wrote use surefire 3.0.0-M4 not 3.0.0-M5...

Comment: @khmarbaise : Thanks for your reply. It did not work with both 2.22.2 and 3.0.0-M4. But when I ran it 3.0.0-M5. It works fine. I will post the entire configuration in the answer. Thanks again

Comment: @johanneslink The issue was with version incompatibility. I upgraded the surefire version to 3.0.0-M5 to make it work. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by updating the version of the surefire and failsafe plugin to `3.0.0-M5` instead of `2.22.1`